# Select a property from a list in another list and use ToString()

Tags: c#, linq, list

I need help to select `FeedItem.Link`  from `List<FeedItem>` that is inside of `List<Feed>` where `Feed.Name` matches a `string` from a `ComboBox` and `FeedItem.Title` matches a `string` from a `ComboBox`. I only need to select one `Link` value, not all of them.

I'm trying to do this with Linq but logs the following in the console, not the mp3link that is:

**System.Linq.Enumerable+WhereSelectEnumerableIterator`2
[Logic.Entities.FeedItem,System.String].**

My Linq code:

```
var feedName = listFlow.SelectedItem.ToString();
var feedItemTitle = listEpisode.SelectedItem.ToString();
var loadFeedData = feedService.GetAllFeeds();

var feedMp3Link = loadFeedData.Where(x => x.Namn == feedName)
                              .SelectMany(x => x.Items)
                              .Where(x => x.Title == feedItemTitle)
                              .Select(x => x.Link).ToString();

Console.WriteLine(feedMp3Link);
```

This is how the class Feed.cs looks like:

```
public class Feed : IEntity
{
    public string Url { get; set; }
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string Category { get; set; }
    public string Namn { get; set; }
    public string UppdateInterval { get; set; }       
    public List<FeedItem> Items { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Did you try using `.SingleOrDefault`?

Comment: Or if there could possibly be many .FirstOrDefault

Answer (score 0):

Try this:-

```
string link = feeds.Where(x => x.Namn == feedName)
                              .SelectMany(x => x.Items)
                              .FirstOrDefault(x => x.Title == feedItemTitle).Link;
```

Please note it may throw `Null reference exception` when no items are found. Alternatively you can use this also:-

```
string link = feeds.Where(x => x.Namn == feedName)
                              .SelectMany(x => x.Items)
                              .Where(x => x.Title == feedItemTitle)
                              .Select(x => x.Link).FirstOrDefault();
```

Answer (score 0):

You are getting the output text seen because you are converting an entire enumeration (i.e. the return value of the final call to `Select()`) to a string. Since the LINQ enumeration class doesn't override `ToString()`, this just gives you the type name, which is what you see in your output.

Instead, you say you want *one* of the values from the resulting enumeration. That would look more like this:

```
var item = loadFeedData.Where(x => x.Namn == feedName)
                       .SelectMany(x => x.Items)
                       .FirstOrDefault(x => x.Title == feedItemTitle);

Console.WriteLine(item != null ? item.Link.ToString() : "Not found");
```

Note that the above assumes, based on the wording of your question, that the `Link` property is not already a `string`. Obviously if it is already a `string`, you don't need to call `ToString()` on it. :)